# Split string into list of two words, repeating the last word

Tags: python, string, list, split

I need to split a string into a list of each two words, but repeating the last word of each pair of words.
Here is what I tried, by using examples I found for other questions:

```
line = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."""

def split_line(in_line):
    line_sp = line.split(" ")
    line_two = [" ".join(line_sp[i:i + 2]) for i in range(0, len(line_sp), 2)]
    return line_two

print(split_line(line))
```

This results into:

```
['Lorem ipsum', 'dolor sit', 'amet, consectetur', 'adipiscing elit,', 'sed do', 'eiusmod tempor', 'incididunt ut', 'labore et', 'dolore magna', 'aliqua.']
```

But what I actually need is this:

```
['Lorem ipsum', 'ipsum dolor', 'dolor sit', 'sit amet', 'amet, consectetur', 'consectetur adipiscing', ...]
```

How can I make it work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `zip` on the following two slices of words:

```
words = line.split()
print(list(map(' '.join, zip(words[:-1], words[1:]))))
```

This outputs:

```
['Lorem ipsum', 'ipsum dolor', 'dolor sit', 'sit amet,', 'amet, consectetur', 'consectetur adipiscing', 'adipiscing elit,', 'elit, sed', 'sed do', 'do eiusmod', 'eiusmod tempor', 'tempor incididunt', 'incididunt ut', 'ut labore', 'labore et', 'et dolore', 'dolore magna', 'magna aliqua.']
```

Comment: The comma at end of each sentence is not omitted in your solution for example see word 'sit amet,' in output. I guess it has to be 'sit amet'.

Answer (score 4):

Simple for loop

```
l = line.split(' ')
result = []
for i in range(len(l) - 1):
    result.append(l[i] + ' ' + l[i+1])
print(result) 
# ['Lorem ipsum', 'ipsum dolor', 'dolor sit', 'sit amet,', 'amet, consectetur', 'consectetur adipiscing', 'adipiscing elit,', 'elit, sed', 'sed do', 'do eiusmod', 'eiusmod tempor', 'tempor incididunt', 'incididunt ut', 'ut labore', 'labore et', 'et dolore', 'dolore magna', 'magna aliqua.', 'Lorem ipsum', 'ipsum dolor', 'dolor sit', 'sit amet,', 'amet, consectetur', 'consectetur adipiscing', 'adipiscing elit,', 'elit, sed', 'sed do', 'do eiusmod', 'eiusmod tempor', 'tempor incididunt', 'incididunt ut', 'ut labore', 'labore et', 'et dolore', 'dolore magna', 'magna aliqua.']
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is [nltk.bigrams()](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.util.bigrams)

```
import nltk
bigrm = list(nltk.bigrams(line.split()))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is 'nltk' in Python standard?

Answer (score 2):

You can start with constructing a list of words in the `line`

```
words = line.split()
```

then you can make a list of lists containing consequential pairs with slicing

```
pairs = [words[i:i + 2] for i in range(len(words))]
```

finally, you can take each pair and joint it with `' '`

```
result = [" ".join(pair) for pair in pairs if len(pair) > 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like, I dont know syntax in python so answering in java.
may be you can convert it to python

```
String line = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";
    String[] split = line.split(" ");
    String [] line_two = new String[split.length-1];

    for (int i = 1; i < split.length; i++) {
        line_two[i-1] =split[i-1] +" "+split[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lazy generator with `zip`:

```
def split_line(in_line):
    line_sp = line.split()
    yield from map(' '.join, zip(line_sp, line_sp[1:]))

print(list(split_line(line)))

['Lorem ipsum', 'ipsum dolor', 'dolor sit', 'sit amet,',
 ...
 'labore et', 'et dolore', 'dolore magna', 'magna aliqua.']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with regex, too:

```
rslt=[ " ".join(tup) for tup in re.findall(r"(\w+)\W+(?=(\w+))",line) ]
```

\w+   one or more word characters;

(\w+) we capture the matched pattern;

\W+   one or more non-word characters;

(?=(\w+))  look ahead as (?=...), but don't step forward, however capture the next word.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever it is worth, just change the iterative value for loop from 2 to 1:

BEFORE:

```
line_sp = line.split(" ")
line_two = [" ".join(line_sp[i:i + 2]) for i in range(0, len(line_sp), 2)]
return line_two
```

FIXED:

```
line_sp = line.split(" ")
line_two = [" ".join(line_sp[i:i + 2]) for i in range(0, len(line_sp),1)]
return line_two
```

print(split_line(line))