# Split string into list of x words, repeating the last x-1 words

Tags: python

I need to split a string into a list containing `x` number of words, but repeating the last `x-1` words.

```
line = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur."
```

if `x = 2`, the output should be:

```
['Lorem ipsum', 'ipsum dolor', 'dolor sit', 'sit amet', 'amet consectetur']
```

if `x = 3`, the output should be:

```
['Lorem ipsum dolor', 'ipsum dolor sit', 'dolor sit amet', 'sit amet consectetur']
```

As per [Split string into list of two words, repeating the last word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51668340/split-string-into-list-of-two-words-repeating-the-last-word), the following code successfully splits the string into 2-word pairs:

```
words = line.split()
print(list(map(' '.join, zip(words[:-1], words[1:]))))
```

However instead of hard-coding the number of words as 2, I would like to specify the number of words `x`, for example:

```
number_of_words = x
def generate_list(x):
```

I have tried playing around with the integers in `print(list(map(' '.join, zip(words[:-1], words[1:]))))`, however the integers only seem to affect the **ordering** of words, rather than the **number** of words.

I imagine I could write separate functions to handle 2-word, 3-word, 4-word scenarios, however ideally I'd like to have one function which handles any `x` number of words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a rolling window of 3 words, you can simply pass one more sliced list to `zip`:

```
list(map(' '.join, zip(words, words[1:], words[2:])))
```

You can therefore use a generator expression to generalize the above expression:

```
def rolling_window(words, number_of_words):
    return list(map(' '.join, zip(*(words[i:] for i in range(number_of_words)))))
```

so that:

```
rolling_window('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur'.split(), 3)
```

returns:

```
['Lorem ipsum dolor', 'ipsum dolor sit', 'dolor sit amet', 'sit amet consectetur']
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to remember the last `x - 1` elements of your iteration to do this properly.

```py
def combinate(sentence, x):
    words = sentence.split()
    return [' '.join(words[i:i+x]) for i in range(len(words) - x + 1)]
```

[IDEOne link](http://ideone.com/qeuFs5)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way.

```
def generate_list(x):
    line = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur."
    words = line.split()
    final_list = []
    for i in range(len(words) - x + 1):
        final_list.append(' '.join(words[i:i + x]))
    return final_list

number_of_words = 3
print(generate_list(number_of_words ))
```

**Output :** `['Lorem ipsum dolor', 'ipsum dolor sit', 'dolor sit amet', 'sit amet consectetur.']`